# PGFPlots marker at specific x values

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikzmark

How can I put a point (mark) in a PGFPlots graph at every x values?

For example, I have the following graph:

[image: graph]

Produced by the following code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} % For \pgfplotstableread
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,trim axis left,trim axis right]
\begin{axis}[
y tick label style={
    /pgf/number format/.cd,
    fixed,
    fixed zerofill,
    precision=2,
    /tikz/.cd
},
enlargelimits=true,
minor tick num=1,
width=\textwidth,
ylabel near ticks,
xlabel near ticks,
ytick={0,0.25,...,1},
xtick={0,1,...,4},
ylabel={Weight $w$},
xlabel={Slot $s$},
]
\addplot[domain=0:4,dashed]{0.31622776601683794^x};
\addplot[domain=0:4.0001,thick,const plot]{0.31622776601683794^floor(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I tried using several `mark` primitives, mark step, mark phase, but was unable to produce the desired output. Desired output:

[image: output]

Comment: You could e.g. add `samples=5` to the second plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That could be done either by just adding `samples=5` to your code or you can even do it a bit simpler.

For more details have a look at the comments in the code.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.14
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    % use this `compat' level or higher to make use of the advanced positioning of labels
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            width=\textwidth,
            ylabel={Weight $w$},
            xlabel={Slot $s$},
            % it is much simpler to use this key instead of defining the list
            xtick distance=1,
            minor tick num=1,
        ]
            \addplot [
                domain=0:4,
                dashed,
            ] {0.31622776601683794^x};
            \addplot [
                % define the marker you want to use ...
                mark=*,
                % ... and how it shall look like
                mark options={
                    color=orange,
                },
                % there is no need to use another domain here
                % (so you can move it to the axis options and delete it
                %  in the two `\addplot' options
                domain=0:4,
                % it seems you only want the values at the integers, so
                % define an appropriate number of samples
                samples=5,
                % and you want the marker on the left of the `const plot'
                const plot mark left,
                thick,
            % done all of the above there is no need for the floor function
            ] {0.31622776601683794^(x)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]